# How to get Minimize, Maximize, and Close buttons on an Electron Application that loads external URL?

Tags: electron

I know that there are tutorials on how to do this, but it seems that those are directed for ones that are coded by the person themselves(using html files). However, mine doesn't have any html files, it simply loads a URL into the session using JS. How would I add pretty much a navbar where I can put all of my buttons(back, forward, close, minimize, etc.), when I'm just loading a URL? I have tried making a separate index.html file that gets loaded as another session and then takes up part of the height of the screen, positioning at the top of the screen, but that did not work, it simply covered up the other session that was loaded from an external URL. My main.js code that sets the browser session is here.

```js
async function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        darkTheme: true,
        icon: 'Logo.png',
        center: 'true',
        resizable: 'true',
        movable: 'true',
        minimizable: 'true',
        maximizable: 'true',
        closable: 'true',
        focusable: 'true',
        fullscreen: 'false',
        frame: 'true',
        width: '800px',
        height: '800px',
        titleBarOverlay: 'color',
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
        }
    })
    
    if (mainWindow.webContents.session === undefined) {
        throw new Error('defaultSession is undefined');
    }
    
    mainWindow.loadURL('https://www.google.com')
    mainWindow.setTitle("GoogleApp")
    mainWindow.setBackgroundColor('#181818')

    mainWindow.webContents.on("did-finish-load", () => {
        mainWindow.show();
    })

    mainWindow.on("page-title-updated", event => {
        event.preventDefault()
    })

    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        mainWindow = null
    })
}
```

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, are your wanting your Electron app to have functionality similar to a web browser with back, forward and reload buttons? In addition, the window is to have standard minimise, maximise / restore, close functionality? If so, you will want to use something similar to an Electron [`<webview>`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/webview-tag). Control the viewed website with html / css/ js crafted back, forward, reload buttons and have a non-frameless [window](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#class-browserwindow). IE: `frame: true`.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much what I need. OK, I will try this out - thank you for the suggestion.